# rails condition one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I want to combine this else if statement into 1 line
My code below displays a partial but only if the current URL is not one of the 3 listed in the elsif statement

```
<% if request.path == landing_path then %>
<% elsif request.path == new_company_path then %>
<% elsif request.path == edit_user_path(current_user.id) then %>
<% else %>
<%= render 'dashboard/user_controls'%>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying

```
<% if request.path != (landing_path || new_company_path || edit_user_path(current_user.id)   ) then %>
  <%= render 'dashboard/user_controls'%>
<% end %>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Explaining what your exact problem is would help direct us in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
<%= render 'dashboard/user_controls' if [landing_path, new_company_path, edit_user_path(current_user)].all? {|path| request.path != path }   )%>
```

But you'd rather abstract this in a helper.